# Remote debugging in intellij

Tags: java, nginx, intellij-idea, jetty, remote-debugging

Trying to do remote debugging my application which is having the following project structure.

outlayer-jar [ contains core components like data source and other components ]
    inner-jar [ the actual source code ]

The application has been deployed using java -jar outlayer-jar.

We are using Nginx server for web request and jetty is internal communication.

While debugging in my local, i can put debug points in outlayer-jar and i can go one by one. But i can't put any debug point in inner jar.

So, i understood like since i'm running outter jar in java command the intellij editor can do the debug only for outter modules.

How to make debug points in inner jar sources also. Thanks in advance!!!

[image]

Comment: When debugging IDE searches for the sources in the classpath of the module, specified in Run/Debug Configurations | **Use module classpath** drop-down. Do you put these jars side by side or one jar depends on another?

Comment: Hi Andrey, i can able to put only one module on class path.. I couldn't find the option to specify both. Please refer the image.

Comment: Hi @Andrey, yes one jar depends on another jar. The server jar depends on core jar.

Comment: Hi, It's working fine now. I have added the following argument in jvm while deploying the application. -Xdebug -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=5005